# How to change texture of chart bar?

Tags: plotting, charts

Is there anyone who know how to make diagonal lines inside the chart bar like the below picture?

[image]

Comment: If any of the answers you got solved your problem, please consider accepting them by clicking the grey checkmark in their left.

Answer (score 10):

There has to be a better way than this:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
 ChartElements -> 
  Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {0.5, 0.05}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: It is great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1 But (@Kim) please read Tufte on Moire patterns and chartjunk.  Kudos to WRI for making this kind of stuff hard to construct.

Comment: @whuber, yes you're right, I forgot myself. I feel guilty now... :)

Comment: Your illustration is a beautiful example of what Tufte writes about: the space between bars really does seem to vibrate, even more so on the screen than on the printed page.  Quite distracting and very useful if your objective is to draw attention away from the data. :-)

Answer (score 6):

With apologies to @whuber and Tufte :)

You can also do the following using `Texture` and `` System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar `` as `ChartElementFunction`.

First, using the function `hatchF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149307/125)

```
ClearAll[hatchF]
hatchF[mf_List: {# &, #2 &}, mesh_List: {50, 50}, 
  style_: GrayLevel[.5], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> mesh, 
  MeshFunctions -> mf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]
```

to create hatched images

```
t1 = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {20}, White, MeshShading -> {Blue, White}];
t2 = hatchF[{# - #2 &, #2 + # &}, {20}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None, 
   MeshShading -> {{Blue, White}, {Red, Yellow}}];
```

And a few `Texture` examples from `ExampleData`:

```
t3 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Metal4"}];
t4 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}];
t5 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Kingwood"}];
```

Then, `Texture` these images and use them as the setting for `PlotStyle` together with `` System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar `` for the option `ChartElementFunction`:

```
BarChart[{3, 2, 3, 4, 3}, 
 ChartStyle -> (Texture /@ {t1, t2, t3, t4, t5}), 
 ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar]
```

[image]

You can go further along this slope:

```
RectangleChart[Tuples[{1, 4, 3}, 2], 
 ChartStyle -> (Texture[ImageMultiply[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], #]] & /@ 
    ColorData[30, "ColorList"]), 
 ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Version 12.1 introduced `HatchShading` which can be used as part of a `ChartStyle` specification:

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
    ChartStyle -> Directive[Blue, HatchFilling[Pi/4, 2]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since Version 12.1 there is also `PatternFilling` which offers countless possibilities.

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
 ChartStyle -> PatternFilling["Weave", ImageScaled[1/20]]]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
 ChartStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Checkerboard", Red, Black}, ImageScaled[1/20]]]
```

[image]