# How do I plot a histogram with hatched shading?

Tags: plotting, histograms, filling

I can plot an ordinary histogram with blue shading and black borders like this:

```
T = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
Histogram[T, 30]
```

And I can simulate hatching like this:

```
T = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
Histogram[T, 30, ChartElements -> Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]]
```

How can I get the hatching and the black borders at the same time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was sure `Histogram` can be modified to have the hatching style. Little late but what about this!

```
g[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := Module[{yval, line},
  yval = Range[ymin, ymax, 15];
  line = Line /@ Transpose@{Most@({xmin, #} & /@ yval),Rest@({xmax, #} & /@ yval)};
  {FaceForm[White],Polygon[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}}],
   Orange, line}];
T = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
Histogram[T, 30, ChartElementFunction -> g,
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thin, Darker@Orange}], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Check in the function where `yval` is defined with `Range[ymin, ymax, 15]` one can change the $15$ to change the amount of hatching. You also have total control of the `Graphics` primitive used in the `ChartElementFunction` so you can use many more `Directive` for example `Opacity` and all.

BR

Comment: Hah. What I was going to do, but ran out of time! +1

Comment: @rcollyer Thx! TThough the `Show` based solution is simpler I thought of trying this solution.

Comment: I upvoted that one, too, as it worked. But, I have an aversion to running things more than once, if I can help it, unless the result is a dramatic speed-up, and the `Show` method runs it twice.

Comment: This twice thing of `Show` forced me to do this!

Answer (score 16):

I would do something like:

```
t = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
a = Histogram[t, 30, ChartStyle -> White];
b = Histogram[t, 30, 
  ChartElements -> Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]];
Show[a, b]
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Here is extended version of [PlatoManiac's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31231/280) which allows changing of the direction of the hatching and also tuning the distance between hatches:

```
g[step_?NumberQ][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
  Module[{yval, lines, xstart, xend},
   yval = Range[ymin, ymax, Abs[step]];
   If[step > 0, {xstart, xend} = {xmin, xmax}, {xstart, xend} = {xmax, xmin}];
   lines = Transpose@{{xstart, #} & /@ Most[yval], {xend, #} & /@ Rest[yval]};
   lines = Join[lines, {{{xstart, Last@yval}, 
           {xstart + ((xend - xstart) (ymax - Last@yval))/Abs[step], ymax}}}];
   {FaceForm[None], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}], 
                                               CapForm["Butt"], Line[lines]}];
```

Now

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
Histogram[data, 30, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> g[-.006], 
 ChartBaseStyle -> {Directive[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], Black}]}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

gives

[image: hist]

And now one can combine several histograms with different hatchings:

```
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1/2], 500];
h1 = Histogram[data1, 30, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> g[.0260], 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], Black, Thin}], 
   Frame -> True];
h2 = Histogram[data2, 30, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> g[-.0180], 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], Black, Thin}], 
   Frame -> True];
Show[h1, h2, PlotRange -> All, BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> False]
```

[image: 2 hists]

The histogram can be optimized by joining adjacent line segments into solid lines and deleting auxiliary points. Here is an example:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100];
hist = Histogram[data, 30, "PDF", ChartElementFunction -> g[-.0160], 
  ChartBaseStyle -> {Directive[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], Black}]}, Frame -> True];

hatchings = Cases[hist, (Line | LineBox)[{x__List}] /; Dimensions[{x}][[2]] == 2 :> x, {0, Infinity}];
hist2 = DeleteCases[hist, (Line | LineBox)[{x__List}] /; Dimensions[{x}][[2]] == 2, {0, Infinity}];

ClearAll[coeff, a, b, x1, x2, y1, y2];
coeff[{{x1_, y1_}, {x2_, y2_}}] /; x1 != x2 = {a, b} /. First@Solve[{a x1 + b == y1, a x2 + b == y2}, {a, b}];
Show[hist2, 
 Graphics[{Line@
    Flatten[Map[SortBy[Flatten[#, 1], Last][[{1, -1}]] &, 
      (Split[#, #1[[2]] == #2[[1]] || #1[[1]] == #2[[2]] &] & /@ 
        Gather[hatchings, coeff[#1] == coeff[#2] &]), {2}], 1]}]]
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `PDF` of a `HistogramDistribution` for the outline.

```
dist = HistogramDistribution[T, 30]

p1 = Plot[PDF[dist, t], {t, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100];

p2 = Histogram[T, 30, "PDF", 
   ChartElements -> Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

The problem here is that it isn't a frequency histogram but a density histogram.

If you want to get counts you need to multiply by the bin width and sample size.

```
p1 = Plot[
  Differences[dist["BinDelimiters"]][[1]]*10^4*PDF[dist, t], {t, -4, 
   4}, PlotStyle -> Black, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

**Edit:**

If you don't want to use `HistogramDistribution` you can also try `HistogramList`.

```
ListLinePlot[
 Thread[{Most[First[#]], Last[#]}] &[HistogramList[T, 30]], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 0, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since Mathematica 12.1 it is possible to do this with `HatchFilling`:

```
Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100], 10, 
 ChartStyle -> HatchFilling /@ (Range[0, 9] π/10)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the method from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152558/125) using  `` System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar `` for the option `ChartElementFunction` together with `Texture` as `ChartStyle`. Images to be used with `Texture` are created using the function `hatchF`.

```
ClearAll[hatchF]
hatchF[mf_List: {# &, #2 &}, mesh_List: {50, 50}, 
  style_: GrayLevel[.5], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> mesh, 
  MeshFunctions -> mf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]
```

**Examples:**

```
SeedRandom[123]
data1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
data2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[2, 1/2], 500];

Histogram[data1, 10, "PDF", 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500,
 ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar, 
 ChartStyle -> Texture[hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {120}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None, 
    MeshShading -> {Gray, White}]]]
```

[image]

```
t1 = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {80}, Gray, PlotStyle->Yellow, MeshShading -> {Gray, Automatic}];
t2 = hatchF[{# - #2 &, #2 + # &}, {50, 50}, Gray, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   MeshShading -> {{GrayLevel[.5], Automatic}, {Automatic, GrayLevel[.6]}}];
t3 = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {80}, White, 
   MeshShading -> {GrayLevel[.5], Automatic}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
t4 = hatchF[{#2 + # &}, {90}, Blue, ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"];

h1 = Histogram[data1, 10, "PDF", 
   ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar, 
   ChartStyle -> Texture[t1], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];
h2 = Histogram[data1, 10, "PDF", 
   ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar, 
   ChartStyle -> Texture[t2], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{h1, h2}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[{data1, data2}, 20, "PDF", 
  ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar, 
  ChartStyle -> {Texture[t3], Texture[t4]},
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since **Version 12.1** there is [HatchFilling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and [PatternFilling](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) with countless options.

```
T = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 10000];
Histogram[T, 30, ChartStyle -> HatchFilling[]]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[T, 30,
 BaseStyle -> Gray,
 ChartStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Hexagon", Orange}, ImageScaled[1/10]]]
```

[image]