# Hatching pattern in ColorRules for MatrixPlot

Tags: plotting

Using `ColorRules` with `MatrixPlot`, how does one get a hatching pattern in one of the cells?

For example, consider the `data`,

```
data = { {1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 3} }
```

And now I consider the `MatrixPlot`,

```
MatrixPlot[data,
 ColorRules -> { 
   1 -> Blue, 
   2 -> Red, 
   3 -> Purple 
   }
 ]
```

[image: matrixplot_example]

**Question:** For the cell with the value `3` and currently with the color `Purple`, how can I get it to have a `Purple` color with a hatched pattern?

Comment: Somewhat related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31221/193

Comment: @belisariusisforth Thanks. I took a look at that link. Perhaps I'm completely missing something, but a "direct" fix is to replace `Purple` above in `ColorRules` with `Graphics[{Black, Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}]` (I can fudge with the color later; the hatching is most important to me). But with that, I simply get this weird maroon color with no hatching. And even if I switch out `Black` to, say, `Yellow` in the above, there is no effect.

Comment: As of v9 Mathematica haven't had  direct support for hatching. Don't know if they did something about it later

Comment: Related: "[Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280)."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As belisarius said, there is no current support for hatching but you could use a graphics overlay as a workaround.

First create the desired pattern and texture a `Polygon` with it:

```
t = Table[{0, n}, {n, -1, 1, 0.1}];

g[c_] := Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[8], Line /@ Transpose[{t, t + 1}]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Background -> c];

pattern2[p_, c_] := Graphics[{Texture[g[c]], Polygon[{
     {p[[1]] - 1, p[[2]] - 1},
     {p[[1]], p[[2]] - 1},
     {p[[1]], p[[2]]},
     {p[[1]] - 1, p[[2]]}},
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}
    ]}]

pattern2[{1, 1}, Purple]
```

> [image]

Create a function to place the pattern over any field of a given value `n`. `matrixLength` is the length of the input data, `c` the color.

```
overlay[patternFunc_, n_, c_, matrixLength_] := 
  Show[patternFunc[#,c] & /@ ({#2,matrixLength + 
     1 - #1} & @@@ Position[data, n])];
```

Example:

```
plot = MatrixPlot[data, ColorRules -> {1 -> Red, 2 -> Orange, 3 -> Purple}]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 plot,
 overlay[pattern2, 3, Purple, Length@data]
 ]
```

[image]

Not the most elegant/efficient solution but it might be useful as a starting point.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks!