# Hatch Fill in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, color, filling

I would like to make the black colour hatched/striped instead of a solid fill, so that when I overlay it on top of another plot, I can still see the colours underneath. I know how to change the opacity of the black, but that doesn't help to see the colours underneath. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
data1 = {{0.004`, 0.00004`, 1}, {0.004`, 0.00005`, 0}, {0.004`, 
0.00006000000000000001`, 0}, {0.005`, 0.00004`, 2}, {0.005`, 
0.00005`, 1}, {0.005`, 0.00006000000000000001`, 1}, {0.006`, 
0.00004`, 5}, {0.006`, 0.00005`, 5}, {0.006`, 
0.00006000000000000001`, 1}};
data2 = {{0.004`, 0.00004`, 0}, {0.004`, 0.00005`, 0}, {0.004`, 
0.00006000000000000001`, 0}, {0.005`, 0.00004`, 1}, {0.005`, 
0.00005`, 0}, {0.005`, 0.00006000000000000001`, 0}, {0.006`, 
0.00004`, 1}, {0.006`, 0.00005`, 1}, {0.006`, 
0.00006000000000000001`, 0}};
plot1 = ListDensityPlot[data1, ColorFunctionScaling -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[structure, 
    Which[structure == 0, White, structure == 1, Blue, structure == 2,
      Green, structure == 3, Yellow, structure == 4, Red, 
     structure == 5, Purple, structure == 6, Gray, True, Black]]]
plot2 = ListDensityPlot[data2, ColorFunctionScaling -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[structure, 
    Which[structure == 0, Opacity[1, Black], structure == 1, 
     Opacity[0, White]]]]
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]
[image: combined plot]

**EDIT:**

This has now been solved for small data sets. For large data sets, however, it does not seem to work. For example, consider these two larger data sets:

[data1BIG](http://www.bartholomewandrews.com/data/data1BIG.dat)
[data2BIG](http://www.bartholomewandrews.com/data/data2BIG.dat)

If I now try to follow the proposed solution:

```
Get["PathToFile/data1BIG.dat"];
Get["PathToFile/data2BIG.dat"];
plot1 = ListDensityPlot[data1BIG, ColorFunctionScaling -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[structure, 
    Which[structure == 0, White, structure == 1, Blue, structure == 2,
      Green, structure == 3, Yellow, structure == 4, Red, 
     structure == 5, Purple, structure == 6, Gray, True, Black]]]
plot2 = ListDensityPlot[data2BIG, ColorFunctionScaling -> None, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[structure, 
    Which[structure == 0, Opacity[1, Black], structure == 1, 
     Opacity[0, White]]]]
Show[plot1, plot2]
plot3 = Normal[plot2] /. 
    Polygon[x_, VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, _] ..}] :> Nothing /. 
   Polygon[x_, ___] :> Polygon[x];
region = RegionUnion @@ Cases[plot3, _Polygon, Infinity];
rp = RegionPlot[region, Mesh -> {40}, MeshFunctions -> {# - 100 #2 &},
    MeshShading -> {Opacity[1, Gray], None}, BoundaryStyle -> None];
Show[plot1, rp, ImageSize -> 500]
```

This causes errors at the `RegionPlot` stage, the first of which is "Boolean region cannot be automatically discretized". I appreciate all the help everyone has put in so far, and if anyone knows how to make this scalable to large data sets, then it will truly come in useful. Many thanks!

Comment: A dot fill would also be fine. Just any type of fill that would allow me to see the colours underneath. Thank you

Comment: This is the closest example that I have found: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98187/hatching-pattern-in-colorrules-for-matrixplot?noredirect=1&lq=1 But I am still stuck with it...

Comment: And this gives some more examples: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64159/generating-hatched-filling-using-region-functionality?noredirect=1&lq=1 I cannot figure out how to apply this to my situation.

Comment: Why not use `Opacity[0.5, Black]`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev That is a sensible suggestion and was indeed the closest I could get to what I wanted initially. However, the problem with using opacity is that, since it is a solid fill, it mixes with the colours underneath to make new colours. This makes the plot very difficult, if not impossible, to read. e.g. White + Opacity[0.5, Black] = gray, Blue + Opacity[0.5, Black] = dark blue, etc. So if I also had, let's say, 'gray' and 'dark blue' as original colours in my plot1, then you can see where the confusion would arise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** With the new-in-version-12.1 directive [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) we can get the desired result with a simple replacement:

```
plot2b = Normal[plot2] /. 
  Polygon[a_, ___, VertexColors -> {Opacity[1, GrayLevel[0]] ..}, ___] :> 
   {Black, HatchFilling[45 Degree, 10, 20], Polygon[a]};

Show[plot1, plot2b]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

1. Post-process `plot2` to remove all the white polygons and `VertexColors` from the remaining
   polygons:

```
plot3 = Normal[plot2] /. Polygon[x_, VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, _] ..}] :> Nothing /. 
   Polygon[x_, ___] :> Polygon[x] ;
```

2. Extract polygons from `plot3` and use [`RegionUnion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html)
   to get a region:

```
region = RegionUnion @@ Cases[plot3, _Polygon, Infinity];
```

3. Use `region` in `RegionPlot` with desired `Mesh*` option
   settings:

```
rp = RegionPlot[region, Mesh -> {40}, MeshFunctions -> {# - 100 #2 &}, 
   MeshShading -> {Opacity[1, Gray], None}, BoundaryStyle -> None];
```

4. `Show` the `RegionPlot` output with `plot1`:

```
Show[plot1, rp, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Use

```
Mesh -> {20, 15},
MeshFunctions -> {# + 100 #2 &, # - 100 #2 &}, 
MeshShading -> {{Opacity[.5, Black], None}, {None, Opacity[.5, Black]}}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful solution. I have upvoted and marked it as correct since you exactly answered the question which I had asked. Unfortunately, this solution does not work on the larger data set which I actually want to use it on :-( (so much for giving minimum working examples...) When trying this with a 50x50 grid, the `RegionPlot` step fails because "boolean region cannot be automatically discretized", among other errors. I will edit my question with further details in the hopes that anybody has time. Thank you again for the quick and detailed response :-)

Comment: @Bart, Thank you for the accept. I will post an update  if i find solution for the larger data sets.

Comment: Thank you, it is much appreciated!