# Shading under a curve with dots

Tags: plotting, filling

I plotted the function $y=x^2$ using the `Plot` command

```
Plot[x^2, {x,-5,5}]
```

I need to shade the area under the curve using a pattern (dots pattern), not using a solid color or a hue. Is it possible? I have found no help about it.

Comment: Related: [\[filling\] hatched](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfilling%5D+hatched).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I plot a histogram with hatched shading?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-do-i-plot-a-histogram-with-hatched-shading)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 29):

This is a simple little hack that will replace the polygons created by your `Filling` command with a set of random points.  By default I'm scaling the number of random points by the number of points in the polygon, so that the density of points stays relatively constant.

```
dotFillPlot[plot_, ndots_: 5] := 
 plot // Normal // 
  ReplaceAll[
   Polygon[a__] :> {PointSize[Small], 
     Point[RandomPoint[Polygon[a], ndots Length@a]]}]

dotFillPlot@Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, Filling -> Axis]
dotFillPlot@
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 4}]], {x, 0, 10}, 
  Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'd rather have a regular grid of points, but that will require a more elaborate function I think - using a `Texture` with the polygons.

If you don't care for the dot's appearance, then you might prefer to manually set the `Opacity` for the dots rather than taking the value from the polygon.  If you put `Opacity[0.6]` right before `RandomPoint` in the function definition, then you get the following plot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How does this approach do with `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"`?

Comment: It does better now, thanks

Comment: You could better scale the number of points with area of a filling polygon, with the help of `RegionMeasure`.

Comment: @BoLe - Thanks, I had tried this (with `Area` instead), but decided it was slowing down the function too much

Answer (score 14):

Try the following. This function makes the dots:

```
lst[m_, stepx_, stepy_] := 
  Flatten[Table[Table[{x, y}, {y, 0, x^2, stepy}], {x, -m, m, stepx}],
    1];
```

Here m is the interval of your plot (in your case m=5), stepx and step y are the distances between the dots in the x and y directions.

This makes the image:

```
Show[{
  Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}],
  Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.01], Point@lst[5, 0.5, 1.5]}]
  }]
```

you can play with stepx and stepy to adjust the distances and with the color and PointSize to get the desired view. the result is:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 8):

One can fill with an arbitrary [`Texture`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html) using this post-processing function:

```
fixFill = Normal[#] /. 
   Polygon[x_] :> 
     Polygon[x, VertexTextureCoordinates ->
       Rescale /@ (x\[Transpose])\[Transpose]] &;
```

Basic usage:

```
tex = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}];

Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}
 , Filling -> Bottom
 , FillingStyle -> Texture[tex]
] // fixFill
```

[image]

This works with complex Filling specifications as well:

```
tex2 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Sailboat"}];

Plot[{x^2, 30 Cos[x/3]}, {x, -5, 5}
 , Filling -> {
     1 -> {Axis, Texture[tex]}, 
     2 -> {{1}, {None, Texture[tex2]}}
    }
] // fixFill
```

[image]

```
(* slow to load if you have not used ExampleData["ColorTexture"] before *)

Manipulate[
 Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}
   , Filling -> Bottom
   , FillingStyle -> Texture[texture]
 ] // fixFill,
 {texture, ExampleData /@ ExampleData["ColorTexture"]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps something like this?

```
plotDot[f_, plotRange_, points_] := Show[
  Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> plotRange],
  ListPlot[
    Select[
      Map[
        {#[[1]]*(plotRange[[1, 2]] - plotRange[[1, 1]])/points + plotRange[[1, 1]],
          #[[2]]*(plotRange[[2, 2]] - plotRange[[2, 1]])/points * GoldenRatio 
          + plotRange[[2, 1]]
        } &, DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[If[EvenQ[x + y], {x, y}],
          {x, 0, points}, {y, 0, points}], 1], Null]],
        (#[[2]] < f[#[[1]]]) &
      ], PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 6}
    ]
  ];

(* Examples *)
plotDot[#^2 &, {{-5, 5}, {-10, 25}}, 40]
plotDot[#^3 &, {{-5, 5}, {-50, 50}}, 50]
plotDot[Sin[#] &, {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}}, 60]
```

[image: Polka dot]

You can control the number of dots with the third argument of `plotDot`. Sadly, you always have to specify the plot range.

Comment: ``plotDot[f_, {x_, min_, max_}, np_Integer?Positive, opts___] := Module[{plt, pts, rng}, plt = Plot[f, {x, min, max}, Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Complement[Options[Plot], Options[Graphics]]]]; rng = Charting`get2DPlotRange[plt]; pts = Select[RescalingTransform[{{0, np}, {0, np}}, rng][Select[Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{0, np}, {0, np}}], 1], EvenQ[Total[#]] &]], (#[[2]] < Function[x, f][#[[1]]]) &]; Show[plt, ListPlot[pts, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 6}, Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Complement[Options[ListPlot], Options[Graphics]]]], FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Graphics]]]]``

Comment: That's one way to come up with something that doesn't need an explicit plot range specification.

Comment: @J.M. That's great. I would only change `rng` definition to not include padding: ``rng = Charting`get2DPlotRange[plt, False];``

Answer (score 6):

Since V 12.1 we have `PatternFilling`

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5},
 Filling -> Axis,
 FillingStyle -> 
  PatternFilling[{"HalftoneGrid", ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]]}, 
   ImageScaled[1/20]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
cba = CoordinateBoundsArray[{{-5, 5}, {0, 25}}, {0.25, 1}];
pts = Map[Select[0.05 < Last@# < First@(#^2) &], cba, {1}];
Plot[x^2, {x, -5, 5}
 , PlotStyle -> Thick
 , Epilog -> {Red, Point /@ pts}
 ]
```

[image]